# Create never ending background service for notification

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, background-service

i have to create an android application which gives a notification when new message is receiving even if the app is not working.     i am using firebase database.   i wrote code for firebase datasnapshot but it only working when app is working i need to run this code if the app is not working.

```
        Mref=new Firebase("https://iyutue-30s49.firebaseio.com/");
    Mref.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

            String value=dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class);
            myDb.GetAllData();
            String idd= String.valueOf(myDb.id);
            if (value.equals(idd)==true){
                NotificationCompat.Builder builder=new NotificationCompat.Builder(getApplicationContext());
                builder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_tab_profile);
                builder.setContentTitle("plaese").setContentText("jijo");
                Intent intent =new Intent(getApplicationContext(),MainActivity.class);
                TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder=TaskStackBuilder.create(getApplicationContext());
                stackBuilder.addParentStack(MainActivity.this);
                stackBuilder.addNextIntent(intent);
                PendingIntent pendingIntent=stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(0,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
                builder.setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
                NotificationManager NM=(NotificationManager)getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
                NM.notify(0,builder.build());
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(FirebaseError firebaseError) {

        }
    });
```

i need to execute this code in background when app is not working also please help me thanks in advnace

Comment: Keeping a connection open while the app is not active will cause serious battery drain and hurt the user experience. Instead it is recommended that you use Firebase Cloud Messaging to notify the user's of events when they don't have the app open.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen but here i use the firebase but this code does't work if the app is not active how to write this type of service thanks in advance

Comment: but other main applications like whatzaap also run background process and service always .. is that not a best way?

Comment: Many apps run background processes. But I highly doubt that Whatsapp would keep a connection open to their servers. Users would rapidly discover the app that drains battery and look for better apps. Most apps implement Firebase Cloud Messaging (formerly GCM) and Apple's APNS to send messages to apps that are not actively being used.

Answer (score 1):

This piece of code needs to be wrapped inside an Android component to be executed. It really depends on what your trigger is. If this is something you want to do in the background, then using a `service` or `broadcastreciever` is your best bet.
As i mentioned, it really depends on the trigger.

For an e.g let's say, you have an app which needs to show a toast when it detects a new SMS. In such case, you need to register for a broadcast and the system invokes the broadcast receiver when an SMS arrives. In the receiver you can put your own logic (like show a toast).

Comment: please give me a suggestions for my case thanks in advance

Comment: What is your trigger point ? When you want to run the code ? Obviously i am hoping you don't wanna run this code continuously in a loop or something

Comment: i need to run  this code when new data is inserted in firebase for give notification even if application is not active also thanks in advance

Comment: In such case, you need to think something on the server side. One of the previous comment  suggests the same  - like using FCM. I don't have any experience if Firebase database can be interfaces with FCM to achieve something like what you want. But no idea at this point